# Replacement software for mice?

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse

I found VIM. but this work on only text editing mode. I want to not use mouse. But i need better than windows accessibility tools

Has any software?

Comment: what functionality do you need that accessibility tools doesn't offer? You can move the mouse cursor and click... I don't see whats missing.

Comment: Yes. I need move cursor to anywhere and click using keyboard easily.

Comment: Why can't you use the cursor keys option in the Accessibility Centre?

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally use MouseKeys, but I usually just use keyboard shortcuts.

- Alt-Tab to switch to the next application
- Ctrl-Tab to switch to the next tab (or to switch windows in a MDI)
- Tab to switch to the next field
- Alt for the menu
- Ctrl-C, -V for cut and past (or Ctrl-Insert, Shift-Insert instead)

[Here's one list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583).  I also use Shift, Alt and Ctrl in combination with the arrow keys and Home and End a lot.  Also take a look at the "keyboard-shortcuts" tag on this site.

For launching apps I use [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use MouseKeys that comes with Windows.

**For XP:**

Control Panel -> Accessibility Options -> Mouse Tab -> "Use MouseKeys".

More info [here](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/mousekeys.aspx).

**For Vista (similar in Win7):**

Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center -> Under "Explore all settings" find "Make the mouse easier to use" -> Under "Control Mouse with the keyboard" select "Turn on MouseKeys".

More info [here](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/mousekeys.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There's [launchy](http://launchy.net/), for launching programs from the keyboard.

There's [vimperator](http://vimperator.org), a Firefox addon that mimicks vim.